# Best practice to share variables between methods within a directive

Tags: angularjs

Let's say i have a simple directive with two methods. In terms of readability i want to have all shared variables on top of the link function.

what's the best way to do this?

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    link: link
  };

  function link(scope,element,attrs){

    var myCustomer = { // same name as directive so it's clear it's a global object
      myCompany: "stackoverflow",
      myCar: "tesla"
    };

    function funcA(){
      config.myCar = "ferrari";
    } 

    function funkB(){
      alert(config.myCar);
    }

    funcA();
    funcB();

  }
```

});

would that be good practice? I'm asking for more complicated cases like async initializing of "myCustomer" keys as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the *directive* `scope`:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-customer.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.myCustomer = {
                myCompany: "stackoverflow",
                myCar: "tesla"
            }

            function funcA() {
                scope.myCustomer.myCar = "ferrari";
            } 

            function funcB() {
                // should be 'ferrari'
                alert(scope.myCustomer.myCar);
            }

            funcA();
            funcB();

         }
    };

});
```

Comment: I tried that, but in my particular use case i get an error, so i wanted to avoid creating a new isolated scope. "Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [dir1, dir2] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div [...]> *directive names changed

Comment: yeah right, and to avoid that i want to know how to structure my code properly, because I do not need an isolated scope right here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .constant('BASE_API_URL', 'http://api.example.com')
    .service('customerService', function customerService ($http, BASE_API_URL) {
        return {
            getCustomer: getCustomer
        };

        function getCustomer() {
            // Returns a promise
            $http.get(BASE_API_URL + '/customer');
        }
    })
    .controller('mycontroller', function ($scope, customerService) {
        $scope.customer = null;

        customerService.getCustomer().success(function (customer) {
             $scope.customer = customer;
        });
    })
    .directive('myCustomer', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'my-customer.html',
            scope: {
                customer: '=',
            },
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {

            // $scope.customer is the customer object

            function funcA() {
                config.myCar = "ferrari";
            }

            function funkB() {
                alert(config.myCar);
            }

            funcA();
            funcB();

        }
    });

<my-customer ng-if="customer" customer="customer"></my-customer>
```